# Print bold text using defualt printer font

Tags: c#, graphics, printing

I just purchased Epson TM-t88v pos printer and made a nice little application to print receipt.

The thing is, I use these lines of codes to print something :

```
graphic.DrawString("TOTAL             " + textBox23.Text,
                   font,
                   new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                   startX,
                   startY + offset + 425);
```

Where font is an arial 10 but **it is substitued by default printer font**, and since I don't want to learn VB is there a way to output this line **bold** even when I am using substituted default printer font?

Note: FontStyle.Bold doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried printing non-bold Arial?

Comment: I'd like to know how this printer works - does GDI render to an in-memory surface on the computer, or are the drawing commands executed on the printer itself? If it's the former, then it's a bug in your code rather than the printer lacking a font, if it's the latter then maybe you should use PCL or PostScript directly instead of GDI.